# Increase number of nodes in quad

Tags: python, scipy, numerical-integration, quad

This might be a simple question, but I am trying to increase number of nodes in quad integration. I could not find relevant documentation about this.

I have a one-dimensional function (Dirac delta-like) which is mostly zero, but non-zero at a very narrow interval. So adaptive quad cannot catch that interval and returns zero. I am trying to catch that peak by sampling at more points. How do you do this? SciPy documentation does not tell much.

The position of this narrow peak changes. I don't know the exact position of the peak.

Comment: Can you give us example code?

Answer (score 0):

[quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine) does adaptive quadrature in 1D with Gauss-Kronrod. You can specify the degree of the Kronrod rules, cranking it up with increase the number of points in the domain.

Install with

```
pip install quadpy
```

and try

```
from numpy import sin
import quadpy

val, error_estimate = quadpy.line_segment.adaptive_integrate(
        lambda x: sin(5*x),
        [0.0, 1.0],
        1.0e-10,
        kronrod_degree=10
        )

print(val)
```

Crank up `kronrod_degree` to get more points in the domain.